# How to show all the elements in a namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces

What can I do to show all the elements inside a namespace in C++?

It's possible to separate namespaces and print them all using Doxygen? Using GCC?

I'm assuming that I do not know the namespace name so I want to print them all or I know a specific namespace name and I want to know what is inside.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ doesn't have reflection (like for example many dynamic languages or Java and .NET) so it is not possible from within C++.

Doxygen can export its data to XML instead of HTML so you can use a XSLT-stylesheet to transform the XML output of Doxygen to whatever format you desire.

There is a version of GCC called GCC-XML which instead of compiling outputs a XML-representation of the the parsed C++ code, here you could do the same.

Last but not least you can of course create a plugin for GCC of Clang and do it in there (GCC for example can use plugins written in Javascript using the Dehydra patch from Mozilla).

I would recommend looking at the Doxygen XML output.

Answer (score 2):

If you are on Linux you can list all symbols from generated binary file using `nm` tool and parse output as you like:

```
nm -C some-app
```

Comment: not really in topic, it's for compiled code and not for source code, also it prints just every symbol

Comment: @user1717079: exact, however the source code is probably compiled and with a little filtering you'll get all the symbols quite easily. (don't forget the `| c++filt` magic).

Comment: @Matthieu M: `-C` key already does `c++filt` magic. However I agree that it would be hard to distinguish namespace names from say class names.

Comment: @ks1322: you need to filter prior to applying `c++filt`. It's much easier. See `nm lib | grep -E " _ZN{pattern}" | c++filt`. The `{pattern}` need be formatted specially, but otherwise it works. For example to get all names in namespace `wikipedia` (top-level) it would be `9wikipedia[0-9]`